# Are there browsers supporting FIDO UAF

Tags: fido, uaf

I'm looking into FIDO UAF (passwordless login) and wondering if there are any browsers supporting it. So far I have only found it used in native mobile apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome, Edge and Firefox all have experimental support. You need to begin looking at the **W3C Web Authentication** standard, which is the pending industry standard that subsumed FIDO 2.0.

Here's a good overview of Edge support: https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2016/04/12/a-world-without-passwords-windows-hello-in-microsoft-edge

See the Chrome feature status:
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5669923372138496